# Clarification of Google Places API for Android/iOS usage terms

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I've been reading through the terms and conditions relating to the usage of Google Places API for both Android and iOS in the context of a free app (free to download & free to use).

The answer lies in the following document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Section 9 deals with limitations, don't be fooled by the double speak and morphing number schemes for the points (read carefully and you'll see what I mean).

Basically an Android app has free unlimited usage as long as "[attribution](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions)" requirements are met, specifically "Powered by Google" displayed prominently for the world to see, plus any attributions for photos available from the metadata.

I had to read it a number of times before finally using a technique called "printing" to permanently project the words on to this stuff called paper before it finally became clear.

Yes you have unlimited usage, go forth and take over the world with your shiny new mobile app, just remember to request an uplift (sorry not enough reputation points for the link, just search for it) before you hit the magic 150,000 hits per 24 hours figure.

My question is what about iOS, your app must be compliant with the Google Maps/Google Earth API Terms of Service but this document specifically states Android with no reference to iOS?
Those amongst you may say rightly so iOS should be damned to the eternal fires, unfortunately it has to be included for the sakes of world domination, as does Windows, Blackberry ...

What say you?
Anyone up for the challenge of clarifying this?
Any Google employees willing to wade in with a definitive answer?

Having had a chance to sleep on it and looking at the subject with fresh eyes the following salient points are shimmering through the double speak:

Everything hinges on Google Maps API terms of use, section 9 "License Requirements".

Looking at section 9.1.1.1 Free access (no fees), yes we comply things are looking up, although it's subject to Section 9.1.2 (Exceptions), this requires closer inspection:

9.1.2.1 Enterprise agreement with Google - since we don't have one this doesn't apply.

moving along ...

9.1.2.2 Mobile Applications - yes it's a mobile application, better read this.

9.1.2.2.1 The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee - relief it's a free app so we can ignore this.

9.1.2.2.2 The rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public access) does not apply ... - this is the part that causes the confusion, but note section 9.1.1.2 Public access (no firewall) is not subject to any exceptions so this can't apply.

Additionally looking at the references in the following sections:

9.1.2.2.1 refers to 9.1.1(a) - THIS SECTION DOES NOT EXIST

9.1.2.2.2 refers to 9.1.1(b) and 9.1.2(a) - THESE SECTIONS DO NOT EXIST

Since these sections make reference to non-existent paragraphs they are not pertinent to the argument.

Does this train of thought make sense to anyone else?